# Find position of every ocurrence of a pattern in Kotlin

Tags: regex, kotlin

I have this large chunk of text in Kotlin. I created a regex pattern to find some substrings within it. Using the findAll function I found every instance that matched the regex pattern. However, I want the exact integer position of every matched instance within the original text. Is there a way to get that directly?

Comment: Assuming the substring isn't fixed, you can first use the regex to find each match, and then use `indexOf()` to find the index of each match. You can pass a `startIndex` argument to `indexOf()` to make sure that you are starting your search deeper and deeper into the string.

Comment: @BenP. There is a much simpler solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`Regex.findAll` returns a `Sequence<MatchResult>`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/-regex/find-all.html), and `MatchResult` has [`range`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/-match-result/range.html), so

```
Regex(yourPattern).findAll(someString).map { it.range.start }
```

will return the sequence of starting indices.